# Installation of pyplot for python 3.5.2

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-3.5

I am trying to import the following statements. My end goal is to generate a word cloud.

I am using `enathught canopy python 3.5.2` In the terminal prompt from `canopy` I ran the command below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
```

which returned `no module names 'pyQt4'`

So i tried installing that `!pip install 'pyQt4'`

output obtained:

```
Collecting pyqt4
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt4
```

Also I tried `!pip install pyplot` which again gave the same `errorno module names 'pyQt4'`

Please help as to what I can do from command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pyQt4. If you are using Anaconda, pyQt5 is included. For some package, they require pyQt4. It took me a long time trying to install pyQt4. My solution is download pyQt4 from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyqt4, and install the .whl file with:

`pip install some-package.whl`